# I'm trying to creating a Queue class, but keep getting an error seemingly to do with generics. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: java

I have a LinkedList class, which serves as the base for a Queue class, which serves as the base for a PrintQueue class.

Here's my PrintQueue class:

```
public class PrintQueue<T> {
    private Queue<T> queue;

    public PrintQueue() {
        queue = new Queue<T>();
    }

    public void lpr(String owner, int jobID) {
        queue.enqueue(new Job(owner, jobID));
    }
}
```

The `queue.enqueue(...)` line, three from the bottom is resulting in an error:

> The method enqueue(T) in the type Queue is not applicable for the arguments (Job)

PrintQueue is a queue of Job objects.

The enqueue method in my Queue class looks like this:

```
    public void enqueue(T item) {
        queue.addToEnd(item);
    }
```

And the addToEnd method looks like this:

```
public void addToEnd(T item) {
    Node<T> itemnode = new Node<T>(item, null); 

    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = itemnode;
    }
    else {
        Node<T> curr = head;

        while (curr.getNext()!=null) {
            curr= curr.getNext();
        }

        curr.setNext(itemnode);
    }

    count++;

}
```

Why isn't this working? All three classes (PrintQueue, Queue and LinkedList) are generic classes .

Comment: How is what you are doing better than the built in class which provide LinkedList and Queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create a `Queue<T>` for some arbitrary type `T` - but then you're trying to enqueue a `Job`.

What do you think it means to enqueue a `Job` on a `Queue<String>` for example?

Do you *really* need `PrintQueue` to be generic? I suspect you just want:

```
public class PrintQueue {
    private final Queue<Job> queue;

    public PrintQueue() {
        queue = new Queue<Job>();
    }

    public void lpr(String owner, int jobID) {
        queue.enqueue(new Job(owner, jobID));
    }
}
```

(Additionally, it's not clear why you've got your own `Queue` class, when there are various good queues in the built-in class library... ones that don't have O(N) "add to end" behaviour, too...)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you method is as :

```
public void enqueue(T item) {
    queue.addToEnd(item);
}
```

Please look at the parameter type, which is `T`. Please make sure the parameter class `Job` is also generic. Once done, call your `enqueue` method as :

```
 queue.enqueue((T)(new Job(owner, jobID)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid confusion, I see that Queue is a custom class and not the java.util.Queue interface.

I strongly suggest that you implement java.util.Queue and not reinvent the wheel. It has only for methods: `element(),peek(),poll(), offer(E) and remove()`.

[Interface Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)